# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths block user interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have an iOS app with `UITabbarController`, and in one tab view there is a `UITableViewController`, when i switch tab i what reload the visible cell row because the row contain a `UILabel` with time and i want refresh the time with the passage of time, but when i tap the tab with the `UITableView`, i use this code:

```
NSArray *visible = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:visible withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

and i call it in `ViewWillAppear`, and with this code takes a moment to open, is not immediate, and with out it is immediate. So how i can refresh that rows without block the UI?

Comment: I would simply put this code in ViewDidAppear:

Comment: glad to help! I created an answer for u :]

Comment: are you using static cell height?

Comment: Also note that the begin/endUpdates bracketing isn't needed in the case like this where you're only making a single table change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the code in `ViewWillAppear:` means it gets run *before* the view has appeared. Since you want animations that the user will see, it makes sense to move this code into `ViewDidAppear`

Don't forget to call `[super viewDidAppear]`!